# jQuery Jcarousel stopped continuous scroll

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

Hello: Thank you for looking at this and helping if you can!

The Jcarousel on the home page did a continuous scroll until I updated to the latest Wordpress version.  Then it stopped.  The left, right buttons stopped working as well.
Here's the website:  http://marcgarrisonphotography.com/

The pics scroll once then it's done.  Nothing happens again until the page is refreshed.

I've read every question I can find on this that seems similar to this problem, have tried some of the different script example and nothing is working.  I'm rather new to this script, and am not sure what things to change or where they are even located.

I see people calling this a plugin, but I don't see any actual JCarousel or JQuery plugin on this website.  I'm found a js folder inside of the wp-admin and wp-includes folders.

Here's is what is in the header.php of the site:

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
{
    // Disable autoscrolling if the user clicks the prev or next button.
    carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
};

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: .01,
        wrap: 'last',
    speed: 10,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
    });
});
```

I've tried changing the wrap to 'continous', changing the auto number and speed, it changes nothing.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thank you so much,
Dee

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your LightBox function is causing problems. While debugging your page, the following error occurs:

```
jQuery(".gallery1 a").lightBox is not a function
Line: 215
```

This could be either because you have a path problem to your LightBox script or just haven't included it in your site.

### Edit

From looking at your source code, you are using two different versions of jQuery: 1.2.3 and 1.7.1. This could also be a reason to why your jCarousel is not working. I would get rid of jQuery version 1.2.3, since that is quite old.

Comment: Ok. Getting rid of the old version of jQuery:1.2.3 sounds like a good place to start.  How do I do that?

Comment: Go to line 58 in your HTML code and remove: <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/jquery-1.2.3.pack.js"></script>

Comment: Hi again,  Line 58 of which html code.  I found it in the Header area, not that far down.  Removed it, it changed nothing.  It's not in the style sheet.